# GTM- Regular expression to match child pages but not the parent that share the same page path

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

Looking for a regular expression for Google Tag Manager that will use the path in a URL but not return it.

For example: `(\/fruit-and-veg\/).*$` will match all of the following:

```
https://www.the-example.co.uk/fruit-and-veg/
https://www.the-example.co.uk/fruit-and-veg/bunch-of-grapes/
https://www.the-example.co.uk/fruit-and-veg/red-pepper/
https://www.the-example.co.uk/fruit-and-veg/green-tomato/
```

I do not want to match on `https://www.the-example.co.uk/fruit-and-veg/`, but I do want to match on the others.

Or another way in GTM to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe `(\/fruit-and-veg\/).+$`? https://regex101.com/r/XPE7Yn/1

Comment: Or, `\/fruit-and-veg(?:\/[^\/]+)+\/?$`

Answer (score 0):

`.*` match any text, empty string included, hence, you allow `/fruit-and-veg/` at the end of string.

Require at least one more character:

```js
\/fruit-and-veg\/.+
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  fruit-and-veg            'fruit-and-veg'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```